# Is there an Angular Table-Element that lets me combine multiple cells in specific rows?

Tags: angular, user-interface

I am looking for a way to build the following table-structure:

```
            |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
            |                       Some Sort of Heading                             |
            |________________________________________________________________________|
            |                 2018                                ||      2019       |
            |-----------------------------------------------------||-----------------|
            |  Okt            |       Nov       |       Dec       ||        Jan      |
            |-----------------|-----------------|-----------------||-----------------|
            | foo | boo | hoo | foo | boo | hoo | foo | boo | hoo || foo | boo | hoo |                
|----------||-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----||-----|-----|-----|
|  Rowname ||  X  |  Y  | Z   |  l  |  m  |  n  |  a  | b   | c   || d   | e   |  f  |
|----------||-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----||-----|-----|-----|
|  Rowname ||  1  |  2  | 3   |  4  |  12 |  14 | 90  | 10  |  1  ||     |     |     |
|----------||-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----||-----|-----|-----|
...
```

with Angular. My problem is the following: I do have 1-12 elements per year (one for each month) and n elements per month.

Is there a structure that does already provide what I want in case I would like not to use the colspan attribute? The best would be if I could even allow to edit specific cells, but that'd be a "bonus", so it is no must-have.

Comment: What does your existing table code look like? Can you use the `colspan` attribute?

Comment: @user184994 I do not yet have table code, since I am still looking for a solution not to use colspan. I am going to edit my post and explain why I would like to avoid colspan

Comment: Edit: Now, as I was writing down my point why not to use `colspan`, I realised that my reasoning for that was stupid. I thought that using colspan would be a mess, since I have 1-12 elements for each year and n elements per month in this table, but this structure might even be so specific, that I'd probably need to write my own structure for it.

Comment: Yep, I think colspan should offer everything you need.